# Sql retrieving data by passing two list to two columns

Tags: sql

I have a table in sql where, I want to retrieve data based on two columns by 
passing a two list of values.
for example:- lets consider a table with table name "employee"

```
-----------------------------
| project_id |  resource_id  |
-----------------------------
|     7      |     46        |
-----------------------------
|     7      |     87        |
-----------------------------
|     5      |     87        |
------------------------------
```

I would like to retrieve data based on exact match of values in both the 
columns just like

```
"select * from employee where project_id = 7 and resource_id = 46;"
```

then it returns the first row. if the query would be like this

```
"select * from employee where project_id in (7,5) and resource_id in 
(46,87);"
```

it will return all the three rows instead of first and third row.
I can understand that the 'sql' engine executes the query by all the 
combination of the values given. but, I need the query to process the data 
for the above values, so as to return the first and third row. Is there any 
solutions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (You have one ANSI SQL compliant answer that may not be supported by all dbms products.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your dbms supports row types etc:

```
select *
from employee 
where (project_id, resource_id) in ((7, 46), (5, 87))
```

ISO/ANSI SQL compliance:

> The following features outside Core SQL-2003 are used:
>
> F641, "Row and table constructors"
>
> T051, "Row types"
>
> F561, "Full value expressions"

(According to http://developer.mimer.se/validator/parser200x/)

Comment: The information you have provided is valuable. but the values that are passed in the arguments in the above case is static. (7, 46), (5, 87). But I need to use sub query in that place.

Comment: I like this solution, because I construct the WHERE clause in VBA from an external fixed table.  Thanks, jarlh

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is:

```
select * from employee 
where (project_id = 7 and resource_id = 46)
   or (project_id = 5 and resource_id = 87)
```

---

Your second query would indeed return all three rows - it essentially asks for any rows where the `project_id` is either 7 or 5 *and* the `resource_id` is either 46 or 87 - all three rows match this criteria.

Where you are going wrong is in expecting the two `IN` clauses to *correlate* to each other.

Comment: What's that `**`?

Comment: I see... Thanks!

Comment: Thank for your valuable reply. But the value i'm gonna pass is not a single data. it will be a list of values.

Comment: Sure, but depending on your input, @ramvinoth, your database may not be able to deal with them directly as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the values you are looking for in a separate table and write query like this (Oracle example):

```
with dataTable as (
select 7 project_id, 46 resource_id from dual
union
select 7, 87 from dual
union
select 5, 87 from dual)
,
 listOfValues as (
select 7, 46 from dual
union
select 5, 87 from dual
)
select * from dataTable where (project_id, resource_id) in (select * from listOfValues)
```